# Show and Hide Menu Bars

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, menu, menuitem, menubar

**I have a set of menu bars which I have been editing**

http://carbonyzed.co.uk/menu/2/ using

http://carbonyzed.co.uk/menu/2/css/style.css and

http://carbonyzed.co.uk/menu/2/js/custom.js ]

I have created these menu bars however instead of it poping out like it currently does, I need **to make it pop out like in**

http://carbonyzed.co.uk/menu/1/ - the css for this one lies withing the index.html file itself

Sorry for posting links, hopefully you can view the code like I did, the **custom.js code** is here

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// Adds title attributes and classnames to list items

$("ul li a:contains('History')").addClass("dashboard").attr('title', 'Dashboard');
$("ul li a:contains('Links')").addClass("pages").attr('title', 'Pages');
$("ul li a:contains('Media')").addClass("media").attr('title', 'Media');
$("ul li a:contains('Campaigns')").addClass("history").attr('title', 'History');
$("ul li a:contains('Messages')").addClass("messages").attr('title', 'Messages');
$("ul li a:contains('Maintenance')").addClass("settings").attr('title',  
'Settings');

// Add class to last list item of submenu

$("ul.submenu li:last-child").addClass("last");

$("ul li:has(ul)").click(function(){
    $(this).find("ul.menu").stop("true", "true").slideDown(500);
    }, function(){
    $(this).find("ul.menu").stop("true", "true").slideUp(500);
});

});
```

I felt that posting the links would be better than posting loads of code.

Thank you to everybody in advance for taking the time to help me with this. I can provide FTP access if necessary to http://carbonyzed.co.uk/menu/

Regards

Henry Aspden

Comment: The Docking facility that http://carbonyzed.co.uk/menu/1/ has is not necessary, however would be cool...